# JS из двух массивов с объектами, сделать один объект

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как из двух массивов с объектами, нужно сделать один объект, где ключами будут объекты первого массива, а значениями объекты второго массива

```
let arr1 = [{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}]
let arr2 = [{id: 4}, {id: 5}, {id: 6}]

result = {
{id: 1}: {id: 4},
{id: 2}: {id: 5},
{id: 3}: {id: 6}
}
```

Comment: да обычным for можно сделать) не совсем понятен вопрос и исходные данные

Comment: вот не хотелось бы for использовать, может есть лучше решение, если нет, то как сделать for ом я знаю)

Comment: Такой синтаксис вообще доступен?

Comment: В js ключ объекта может быть только строкой или символом (https://learn.javascript.ru/object)